# Homebrew cask install without multiple password prompts

Tags: homebrew

When installing certain casks, homebrew asks for the password multiple times. For example with zoom, it prompts for password 11 times before it installs (snippet attached)
[image]

How can I get homebrew to ask for the password just once? or better yet, never?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you change your _sudoers_ file? By default, giving the password to `sudo` once gives you a 5-minute window to use `sudo` without entering the password again.

Comment: it is possible with SUDO_ASKPASS. Look at this https://github.com/reitermarkus/dotfiles/blob/3219808b4e8379057dcb3dde984d655c6d094ac8/.sh or https://github.com/rofrol/dotfiles/blob/116f7594d8d03043b590057df165586e28b5cd29/bin/brew-update